# Angular 4: Is the circular dependency my only option?

Tags: angular, angular5

In my page, I have 2 types of layout: step-layout and group-layout, both of them can have an array of childLayouts, the type of childLayouts could be both of themselves:

Here is an example of step-layout S1 contains group-layout G, and G contains another step-layout: S2:

[image: enter image description here]]

Codes below:

In the step-layout.html:

```xml
<!--
 elements of step-layout 
-->
<section *ngFor="let layout of childLayouts">
    <section [ngSwitch]="layout.functionType">
        <step-layout *ngSwitchCase="EType.STEP" [layout]="layout"></step-layout>
        <group-layout *ngSwitchCase="EType.GROUP" [layout]="layout"></group-layout>
    </section>
</section>
```

In the group-layout.html:

```xml
<!--
 elements of group-layout 
-->
<section *ngFor="let layout of childLayouts">
    <section [ngSwitch]="layout.functionType">
        <step-layout *ngSwitchCase="EType.STEP" [layout]="layout"></step-layout>
        <group-layout *ngSwitchCase="EType.GROUP" [layout]="layout"></group-layout>
    </section>
</section>
```

Then I got the circular dependency warning.

I'd like to know in my case, is there anyway to avoid the circular dependency? Or it is my only option?

Comment: Is there a reason why step layout and group layout need to be separate components?, both of their templates are identical so it might be a good idea just to have one component and that would solve your circular dependency issue.

Comment: @CarlosRincones Thanks! I've considered this. But thing is there are actually 4 types of layout in the requirement :D ... That means there will be massive *ngIf / switch-case stuff in the code if I make all of those layouts in one component